# Css 100% height just wont work

Tags: css, height

I want my div.container to be 100% height to fill the whole screen. 
I've tried a few things, min-height, body height 100% and all of them seperate but it just won't work.

Here is the link : http://jquery.colinvaneenige.nl/test/

So .container with 100% height while still being in the center of the page! :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you need to make the `html` have `height:100%` as well..

Comment: I've also tried that but it still won't work!

Comment: what doesn't work ? if you set the `html` then the `.container` also gets 100% of screen.. check it with firebug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it `position: absolute` at set the `top` and `bottom` to `0`:

```
#container {
   width: 400px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: red;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/TheYaXxE/V6DBM/2/)

..or

```
body,html {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

#container {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/TheYaXxE/V6DBM/3/)

Comment: That did it for one part! thanks! Now it is stuck to the left and margin: 0 auto; wont fix that any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second one did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Yep. Use left: 0 and right: 0. Then you can use margin: 0 auto. See my updated answer and Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: absolute` and set `height: 100%` instead of min-height.

```
.container {
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
}
```

You then will have to use other CSS tricks to get it back to centered, such as let's say your width of the container is 1000px:

```
.container {
     width: 1000px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -500px; /* negative half of the total with of the container */
     /* And code from above line */
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever been successful with this by creating a table with a single cell that is 100% height, then placing your div within that.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible, height must be in pixel :/
Only % for width :)
You can make a " min-height: 100px; "

Comment: That is not true. 1. It is absolutly possible. 2. You can use percentage for width and height.

Comment: Oh dear. Lets quickly teach you! [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5Rw74/)